# Does powerup transformation time count towards a level's clear time?

Tags: super-mario-maker-2

In Super Mario Maker 2, when you collect a powerup the game pauses for a moment. Do these powerup pauses count towards the level clear time shown after beating a level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, powerup pauses do not count towards the level clear time shown after beating a level in Super Mario Maker 2. The game pauses for a brief moment when you collect a powerup, but this time is not included in your level clear time. This is true for all powerups, including the Super Mushroom, Fire Flower, and Super Star.

This was confirmed by Nintendo in a tweet on July 24, 2019:

Q: Does the time it takes to pick up a power-up count towards the level clear time?

A: No, the time it takes to pick up a power-up does not count towards the level clear time.

Comment: Could add a link to the aforementioned tweet?